# How to Upload image in magento 2 using UiComponent

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, adminhtml, image-upload

I am trying to upload Images with a custom module in Magento admin

```
 <field name="recipes_image">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">recipe</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                        <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Dac_Recipes/image-preview</item>
                        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="recipes/test/upload"/>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```

`$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`  image filed empty

controller

```
<?php
namespace Dac\Recipes\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Dac\Recipes\Model\Recipe as Recipe;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Edit A Contact Page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();

        $contactDatas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('recipe');

        if(is_array($contactDatas)) {

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

Comment: how does the controller that you declared in the xml looks like? the one that answers to `recipes/test/upload`.

Comment: **recipes/test/upload**  only for image and   **class NewAction extends** all   form data

Comment: Please help me.